# Synchronization is finished but last_sync_status is still 1

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

Don't ask me about this weird set up, it was something that was given to me.

I have a replication set up from on server to another that does a lot of different stuff. After the replication has finised it relies on a trigger that is set on the MSSubscription_gents table. The trigger updates another table when the `last_sync_status` is set to 2, which is the value it should have when the replication is finished.

This is all set up in production and I am trying to set up a QA environment with the same setup but for some reason it doesn't work. The table is updated with a new value for `last_sync_time` but the `last_sync_status` is stuck at 1 and the trigger doesn't fire.

Any good suggestion what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem in my case.

The database I was publishing to was a backup of an older database which already had som data in the replication tables. Removing the publication, the replication tables in the target database and than setting up publication again resolved the issue.